# What can I do with Bhut Jolokia's?

Tags: chili-peppers

I'm growing some Bhut Jolokia's (world hottest pepper aka ghost pepper) amongst other hot peppers. Anyone have any recommendations what I can do with them? I picked one off the plant last night. I'm looking for something other that hot sauce or chili.

Comment: Well, if you have some gullible friends... :P

Comment: Bhut Jolokiaa make for great Youtube videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used bhut jolokias but I love spicy vegetable oil.  DO NOT just throw the peppers in a jar of oil. Apparently this is bad. Follow the much more helpful links in the comments that follow this and make the oil properly.

Once you do this you can cook pretty much anything that needs a little (or a lot) of extra heat.  You said you have other peppers so it might be interesting to set up a few jars with different pepper combos.

Bonus: if what I've heard of these peppers is correct, you can probably make a low grade mace this way.

If you're looking for something to do right away, I'd mix a *very* small piece in some melty cheese and throw it on some chips, burritos, pizza, or anything really. Spicy cheese rocks.

Good luck and enjoy.

Comment: Don't do this... http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/why-did-my-hot-pepper-oil-get-moldy

Comment: This way of making flavored oil is highly unsafe; it carries a serious risk of botulism: http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09340.html

Answer (score 3):

I once made habanero poppers for some friends.  Sliced the habaneros in half length wise and seeded them. I stuffed them with a mix of cream cheese, monterey jack, sour cream, salt and pepper and then baked them in the oven until the cheese had turned GB&D.

They were very tasty, as the pepper itself was quite a bit sweeter and more flavorful than the normal jalapeno I would have used. I would expect that since the bhut jolokia is in the same general family as the habanero, the same would apply here.  However, they were significantly hotter, almost to the point of unpleasant for the non-chiliheads.

As the bhut jolokias are even hotter, I would urge caution when handling them.  I would also probably enjoy every moment of the pain of eating them.

Answer (score 2):

maybe use it to infuse some vodka, and make a really spicy vodka for cocktails?

Comment: that would make a nice addition to Pasta Diablo