# Why did my hot pepper oil get moldy?

Tags: oil, chili-peppers, mold

While following the advice in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/what-can-i-do-with-bhut-jolokias/16736#16736) I placed two ripe Bhut Jolokia peppers in a fresh bottle of olive oil, and put it on the shelf to sit for a month so the heat from the peppers would infuse the oil.

However, one of the peppers became covered with white mold.

The two peppers were put in at different times, as they ripened, since I only got half a dozen peppers from the plant, and they all ripened at different times.

The first pepper went into what had been an unopened bottle of olive oil, after I cut out a small blemish, and removed the stem and top of the pepper.  It floated at the top of the oil for a few days, perhaps as long as a week, before sinking to the bottom of the bottle.

The second pepper was added about 1.5-2 weeks later, and was more intact (there was no blemish, so I only removed the top to remove the stem and expose the seeds).  That pepper floated on the surface as well, but about 1.5-2 weeks later, I noticed that it was still floating, and was now covered with a patch of fluffy white mold just above the surface.

What did I do wrong here?  How could I prevent this from happening next time?

Comment: I'm watching the answers. I had something similar happen to me about a month ago. The mould was sort of puffy-looking and translucent. The difference: My pepper had been cut open to expose the inside and had sunk to the bottom (and stayed there for about 2 weeks before the mould appeared). The alternative to cold infusions seems to bee heating up the oil with the pepper and then putting them back in the jar (after they cool), but that much hot oil kinda scares me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately...I think that other answer gave some dangerous information.

Sticking a raw pepper in oil and letting it sit out is dangerous.  Not only could the moisture cause mold apparently but sticking something like that in oil runs the risk for botulism.

You could reduce the risk of mold by using dried peppers, but botulism is still there.

Comment: Can you bake them or anything to kill the bugs? or soak them in vinegar or anything?

Comment: @Rikon You're not going to be able to heat them high enough in a homemade product and still have a usable ingredient afterwards.  Making them more acidic should help.  Chili infused vinegars don't have the same issue because of the PH.  If you sterilize the jars and soak the chilies in vinegar first, then put them in the oil, and refrigeration  - you'd be much better off.  This is basically what the USDA requires now, both acid and refrigeration to reduce the botulism risk.

Comment: rfusca is correct. You should never, ever make flavored oil this way.  Always heat it to at least 160F for 20 minutes with the flavoring ingredients (exact temps/times can vary).  Infusing raw peppers into cold oil carries a serious risk of botulism: http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09340.html

Comment: That linked articled from CO state backs up my acid comments, get the PH below 4.6 to be safe.

Comment: @rfusca: Would the chiles have to drain the vinegar and dry out before putting them in the oil or would it be OK to put a chile still dripping in vinegar into the oil? I don't really want an infused vinegar, I'm not sure it could be used the same way as an oil. Do you have a link to this process in more detail (or can you describe it in more detail)?

Comment: I find taking the seeds and heating them in oil is great for drawing out the spice/flavor.  That can be done and then added back in to the rest of the oil no?

Answer (score 0):

As a former Angina suffer I am always concerned with blood circulation and I am regular to eat hot peppers. If you are placing your peppers in oil to preserve them I would rather suggest to simply thread them with an ordinary needle and thread...hang them up in any convenient place to dry. Air drying will not produce mold and I have had strings lasting 3 years in my kitchen. Cut off one or two as you wish...works for me. (They look awesome too) 
Secondly, if you do wish to put them in oil for your purpose, heat the oil and place place in the oil let it cool, remove and discard the peppers(or eat now) ...viola spicy oil...keeps well in the ref. for several months.
Lastly, try this ... add peeled garlic, carrot slices small pearl onions and some of your favorite seasoning  such as Sage, tarragon,peppercorns,  rosemary sprigs, fill with apple cider vinegar....close tightly.refrigerate ...after about a month these will be awesome as a garnish or for spicy nibbling. The vinegar will not allow bacteria and for your taste buds and heart....they will love you too.

Answer (score -2):

As one who loves to cook and eat Italian, going as far as to continue the time consuming process of making my own tomato passata and ready made sauce..I have learned that anything you jar, or want to keep in a jar needs to be heated to a boiling point for 30 minutes, ensuring that you have killed all sources of bacteria and other bad stuff. Failure to do so will present you with exploding jars, and a chance to become very ill, and perhaps worse...just read the instructions provided by your mason jar manufacturer, buon appetito

Comment: This is not actually the case. Pasteurisation can be carried out at lower temperatures, but the time required is a function of the temperature. Food safety regulators publish tables.